# How to transform url with parameters into direct link?

Tags: php

Since I'm no programmer, I run into lots of doubt when asking google for help as I don't know the specific technical names of what I'm looking for.

So, I'll try to be specific

I got a page (domain/courses.php?id=name_of_the_course) and want it to be like (domain/name_of_the_course). Is it possible? I see it running pretty well on Wordpress where wordpress/blog?id=blog_title is shown as wordpress/blog_title

Eg: I want this

- domain.com/courses.php?id=Cosmethology
- domain.com/courses.php?id=Pharmacology

(all the courses are on a database)

To be shown this

- domain.com/Cosmethology
- domain.com/Pharmacology

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look for "SEO friendly URLs", "clean URLs" or "URL rewriting".

Comment: Yes, you can do it definitely but as you said you are not programmer so, how you will do it? As it can be done through programming.

Comment: So many of us here can help you out with some great code, but, would you consider Wordpress and some hints on how to achieve this as an answer?

Comment: Aparna and Charl, if at least know the names of what I'm looking for I can easily get help on google. 

I used to work with Wordpress, but so many bugs and site crashes that I've decided making all in php under a html5/css3 base. My major problem is that sometimes I don't have a clue of what the technical term is used for a better search ;)

I work with training and got a site where lists and shows all courses I offer. I'm no satisfied the way I built it, with page.php?id=name of the course; I wanted to make it simpler for customers and students with more friendly url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

courses.php:

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: /'.strtolower($_GET['id']));
?>
```

Make sure there is nothing in the file before the `<?php` INCLUDING SPACES OR BLANK LINES. That will basically break the above from working at all.

Comment: OK, I'll try this. Thanks. 
I found this too [link]https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/[/link]

Comment: My syntax may not be perfect but that's the gist.

Comment: @EduardoWöetter For the record, that link uses HTTP server configuration settings, which will also work, but I thought you were asking how to do it in PHP. Depending on where your PHP will be running, you might not have the ability to do it the way that page describes. My solution works entirely in code. HTH.